# Contact form {"error":true,"message":"404 not found!"}

Tags: php, contact-form, prestashop-1.7, jsondecodeerror

I got an error after sending contact form and the message doesn't come in my admin panel. Any ideas?

```json
{"error":true,"message":"404 not found!"}
```

[image]

PHP version: `7.3.33`

PrestaShop version: `1.7.8.8`

Request URL: https://oneride.eu/en/contact-us
Request Method: `POST`
Status Code: `200`
Request Form Data:

- id_contact: `2`
- from: `mail@mail.com`
- id_order: `708`
- fileUpload: (binary)
- message: `test`
- psgdpr_consent_checkbox: `1`
- url:
- token: `a3511a4e2dcb2717ab336e20b8ca69b3`
- submitMessage: `Send`

Debug mode //oneride.eu/en/contact-us :

```
(1/1) ContextErrorException
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

in tawkto.php line 135
at Tawkto->hookDisplayFooter(array('smarty' => object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 1007
at HookCore::coreCallHook(object(Tawkto), 'hookDisplayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 13
at Hook::coreCallHook(object(Tawkto), 'hookDisplayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 431
at HookCore::callHookOn(object(Tawkto), 'displayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1))
in Hook.php line 944
at HookCore::exec('displayFooter', array('smarty' => object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 1), null)
in smarty.config.inc.php line 167
at smartyHook(array('h' => 'displayFooter'), object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in SmartyLazyRegister.php line 83
at SmartyLazyRegister->__call('smartyHook', array(array('h' => 'displayFooter'), object(SmartyCustomTemplate)))
in a7a56b2fa98f8bb9c3e9557be5244fafdabbb7d0_2.file.footer.tpl.php line 78
at Block_99635320563e3665eedae42_10577993->callBlock(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_99635320563e3665eedae42_10577993), object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 184
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), object(Block_99635320563e3665eedae42_10577993))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 156
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->instanceBlock(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'Block_99635320563e3665eedae42_10577993', 'hook_footer')
in a7a56b2fa98f8bb9c3e9557be5244fafdabbb7d0_2.file.footer.tpl.php line 30
at content_63e3665eee0747_13776542(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('file:_partials/footer.tpl', null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 31536000, array(), 0, false)
in e2edce3fe10e6aa05aff7c1599af26310b1ccbc7_2.file.layout-both-columns.tpl.php line 358
at Block_19810866863e3665eb94015_33088710->callBlock(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 248
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->callBlock(object(Block_19810866863e3665eb94015_33088710), object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 184
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->process(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), object(Block_19810866863e3665eb94015_33088710))
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 156
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->instanceBlock(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'Block_19810866863e3665eb94015_33088710', 'footer')
in e2edce3fe10e6aa05aff7c1599af26310b1ccbc7_2.file.layout-both-columns.tpl.php line 116
at content_63e3665eb98d98_63460293(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl', null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 31536000, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl')
in a1098b2decf1c96dbbc1848914cf81e44e633a60_2.file.layout-left-column.tpl.php line 38
at content_63e3665eb7f348_92763673(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('layouts/layout-left-column.tpl', null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 31536000, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'layouts/layout-left-column.tpl')
in e29f4ab1fe55858e6b724549e36e5445b5a2720b_2.file.page.tpl.php line 33
at content_63e3665eb76d59_43901630(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render()
in smarty_internal_template.php line 385
at Smarty_Internal_Template->_subTemplateRender('page.tpl', null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', 0, 31536000, array(), 2, false, null, null)
in smarty_internal_runtime_inheritance.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Inheritance->endChild(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), 'page.tpl')
in df1c39e008529093e0cd15f27cf1f604eb7202df_2.file.contact.tpl.php line 50
at content_63e3665eb6b637_82232812(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_resource_base.php line 123
at Smarty_Template_Resource_Base->getRenderedTemplateCode(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_template_compiled.php line 114
at Smarty_Template_Compiled->render(object(SmartyCustomTemplate))
in smarty_internal_template.php line 216
at Smarty_Internal_Template->render(false, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 232
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(object(SmartyCustomTemplate), null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', null, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch('contact.tpl', null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl', null, false, true, false)
in SmartyCustom.php line 112
at SmartyCustomCore->fetch('contact.tpl', null, 'at_moviclayouts/layout-left-column.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 727
at FrontControllerCore->smartyOutputContent('contact.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 709
at FrontControllerCore->display()
in Controller.php line 326
at ControllerCore->run()
in Dispatcher.php line 525
at DispatcherCore->dispatch()
in index.php line 28
```

I updated prestashop and modules via **1-Click Upgrade** and rolled back to default templates

Comment: Can you fix this issue first?
`json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: I don't know where. This function isn't in contact form module.

Comment: Do you have access to the actual php files? If you do, can you search through them for the file which has this `section id="content"` inside? The reason - since that's what contains your JSON error, perhaps you could start from there, and find how that HTML element gets its contents.